# Background execution in Xamarin.Android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to execute some code in background in my `Xamarin.Android` app. For example, make a HTTP request and do some actions on server side, get a response and update UI.

So, should I really use Android specific components like `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, etc for that? Can I just run my code in `Task.Run`? Are there useful methods in C#/Mono to achieve my purpose?

Comment: If you are performing those background actions while the app is in the foreground, then yes, Task.Run to use a thread from the working pool is fine. If you are looking at performing actions while the app is in the background then platform-based coding is required, review the new Android WorkManager that handles all the various API level idiosyncrasies: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [C# model of asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), it is used extensively in most Xamarin applications. Basically, your methods return "async Task" objects, which you can then "await" without blocking the UI thread.

**EDIT**

I also found some [related information specific to Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/async).